# OutOfMemory while editing XML for Android in Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, out-of-memory

I create Android applications for my job.  Eclipse is open all day and I am frequently editing XML files for layouts, etc.
I find that creating/editing these XML files pushes up the memory use of Eclipse.  Eclipse never seems to release any of the memory and eventually Eclipse tells me that there has been some sort of workbench out of memory error and I have to exit.  It will not let me save or do much of anything after this point.

Is there a workaround for this?
I don't want to have to exit Eclipse and start it up because of this memory issue.
Why won't Eclipse free up its memory use? It just keeps going up.

edit: I am still having issues with running out of memory, the eclipse.ini suggestions did not fix it.

Comment: How much RAM do you have on your workstation? Can you reproduce the problem on other workstation with different configuration?

Comment: Yes this has happened on multiple computers.

Work computer: 2gb ram, 32bit win7
Home desktop: 4gb ram, 64bit win7

java version: 1.6.0_21-b07

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What version of Eclipse and JDK are you using?

Try [this **eclipse.ini**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/142357/what-are-the-best-jvm-settings-for-eclipse/3275659#3275659), and check that you are using a JDK1.6.0_u21b7 (build 7) for launching your eclipse.
With JDK1.6.0_u21b6, out of memory were frequent.

Comment: java version 1.6.0_21
build 1.6.0_21-b07, was using eclipse 3.4.2 but now trying out 3.5.0 after making some changes to eclipse.ini.  thanks for including the eclipse.ini posting, i'll come back if the issue isn't resolved

Comment: @binnyb: actually you could try the latest 3.6 Helios version, with the optimized eclipse.ini.

Comment: @VonC: quote from http://developer.android.com/sdk/eclipse-adt.html "Caution: There are known issues with the ADT plugin running with Eclipse 3.6. Please stay on 3.5 until further notice." So i guess google doesn't want people using 3.6 for android development yet

Comment: @binnyb: true, in that case, try the 3.5 `eclipse.ini` from link I reference.

Comment: the eclipse.ini suggestions did not seem to fix it. ugh

Comment: @binnyb: sorry to read that. Eclipse3.5.2 and java1.6.0_21b7 and improved `eclipse.ini` didn't help then?